# Bitmap Memory Error Android

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I am making an Android game, but when I load my Bitmaps, I get a memory error.  I know that this is caused by a very large Bitmap (it's the game background), but I don't know how I could keep from getting a "Bitmap size extends VM Budget" error.  I can't rescale the Bitmap to make it smaller because I can't make the background smaller.  Any suggestions?

Oh yeah, and here's the code that causes the error:

```
space = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.background);
    space = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(space,
            (int) (space.getWidth() * widthRatio),
            (int) (space.getHeight() * heightRatio), false);
```

Comment: Have you tried inSampleSize? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to sample down the image.  You can't "scale" it down smaller than the screen obviously, but for small screens etc it doesn't have to be as high resolution as it is for big screens.

Long story short you have to use the inSampleSize option to downsample.  It should actually be pretty easy if the image fits the screen:

```
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final int dimension = Math.max(display.getHeight(), display.getWidth());

    final Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    InputStream bitmapStream = /* input stream for bitmap */;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapStream, null, opt);
    try
    {
        bitmapStream.close();
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        // ignore
    }

    final int imageHeight = opt.outHeight;
    final int imageWidth = opt.outWidth;

    int exactSampleSize = 1;
    if (imageHeight > dimension || imageWidth > dimension)
    {
        if (imageWidth > imageHeight)
        {
            exactSampleSize = Math.round((float) imageHeight / (float) dimension);
        }
        else
        {
            exactSampleSize = Math.round((float) imageWidth / (float) dimension);
        }
    }

    opt.inSampleSize = exactSampleSize; // if you find a nearest power of 2, the sampling will be more efficient... on the other hand math is hard.
    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    bitmapStream = /* new input stream for bitmap, make sure not to re-use the stream from above or this won't work */;
    final Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapStream, null, opt);

    /* Now go clean up your open streams... : ) */
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it a bitmap resource?  Actually, scratch that, you can use a different `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` method that takes a resource or whatever you can get a hold of : )

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

From the Android Developer Website, a tutorial on how to efficiently display bitmaps + other stuff. =]

Answer (score 0):

- I don't understand why are you using `ImageBitmap`? for background. If its necessary , its okay. Otherwise please use `Layout` and set its background because you are using background image.
  This is important. (Check Android docs. They have clearly indicated this issue.)

You can do this in following way

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_background);
 backgroundRelativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

- In most android devices the Intent size equals 16MB.  You MUST Follow these instructions [Loading Large Bitmap Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)